# "Some researches show" or "some research works show"?

Tags: grammatical-number

Which one is more idiomatic? Can *research* be pluralised?

> Some researches show that ...

or

> Some research work show that ...

Or other more idiomatic suggestions?

Comment: Some research shows...

Comment: Some studies show ...

Answer (score 2):

"research shows" is much more common than "researches show", and therefore is more idiomatic.

[Google NGram showing difference](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=research%20shows%2C%20researches%20show&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cresearch%20shows%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cresearches%20show%3B%2Cc0)
Google search for "research shows" - 23.4 million results
Google search for "researches show" - 64,900 results
ratio of 668 to 1

The difference being whether it's used as a count noun or not. The problem in knowing whether it is used today comes from the fact that many of the results I've checked are either from old writings, from sources that are non-English, or from authors that aren't native English speakers.

Here are some examples:

> ...yet this account of his electrical researches shows a complete
>   ignorance of Cavendish's unpublished work...
>  [The Electrical
>   Researches of the honourable Henry Cavendish (written 18th century,
>   edited 19th century](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=Lvw8AAAAIAAJ&pg=PR48&lpg=PR48&dq=%22researches%20shows%22&source=bl&ots=8ZwPgIvgGq&sig=FIQBXPbppGxTbq3TdsqdolSW7G0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjGjPKugabeAhUFeysKHVnpDUYQ6AEwB3oECAIQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22researches%20shows%22&f=false)
>
> ...printed Researches show that no bodies but electrolytes have this
>   relation to heat and energy...
>  [Experimental Researches in Electricity: Series 15-18 by Michael Faraday, from 19th century](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=EvYWAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA213&lpg=PA213&dq=%22researches%20shows%22&source=bl&ots=rSdq0d-UK3&sig=ki6A-U2BYlVMz3oqYQySlIu8RJg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjGjPKugabeAhUFeysKHVnpDUYQ6AEwCHoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22researches%20shows%22&f=false)

Also Darwin's famous [Voyage of the Beagle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Voyage_of_the_Beagle) was republished as Journal of Researches in the 19th century.

On the other hand, modern examples include instances I found on Facebook. It's hard to know whether using "researches" in some cases is a result of unfamiliarity with modern English.

For example, I found it used in s book called "e-Learning, e-Education, and Online Training", based on the proceedings of an international conference held in 2018 in Shanghai. All of the names on this publication either have a non-English-sounding name in some way. It's impossible for me to know whether this is a factor.

Another example of "researches" is in a book summarising the proceedings from a different conference held in China.

One instance found in a PubMed search, an article named "Leptin and food status in gastropancreatoduodenal pathology."

Note: [Article in Russian]

So I've individually looked at instances of "researches", and found so far that they have hallmarks of being writing originating in non-English sources. However, I can't say that "researches" isn't used in English. My feeling is that it is used, can be correct, but is not the popular form. So best to stick to "some research shows", not "some researches show".

Comment: I agree that "researches" is not idiomatic. And the dictionary examples speak of multiple researches of the same researcher. However, the problem with "some research shows" is that it could be exactly one.

Comment: @michael.hor257k You found "researches" in dictionaries? I see, I totally missed that in my answer. Also I didn't consider the possible nuance between the two in meaning. Thanks.